# How to send multiple emails with ASP.NET VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do I set the code below to generate multiple emails like with a reminder every 15 minutes? Thank you for any guidance.

```
Private Sub SendEmail(ByVal pharmEmail As String, ByVal backupEmail As String)
Dim smtpClient As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
Dim message As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()

Try
    Dim fromAddress As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EmailFromAddr"), WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EmailFromName"))
    message.From = fromAddress
    message.To.Add(pharmEmail)
    message.Subject = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EmailSubject")
    message.Priority = Net.Mail.MailPriority.High
    If (WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("backupEnabled") = True) Then
        message.CC.Add(backupEmail)
    End If
    message.IsBodyHtml = True
    Dim orderURL As New HyperLink
    orderURL.Text = "here"
    orderURL.NavigateUrl = "http://" & WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ServerName") & "/User/ReviewOrder.aspx?orderID=" & webOrderID
    message.Body = "An order was created using the account of " + Profile.FirstName.ToString() + " " + Profile.LastName.ToString() + ". " + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EmailBody") + "<a href='" + orderURL.NavigateUrl + "'>here.</a>"
    'message.Body = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EmailBody") & " " & orderURL.
    smtpClient.Send(message)
Catch ex As Exception
    ErrorHandler.WriteError(ex.ToString)
    Throw ex
End Try
```

Comment: You're going to need a [library capable of running background tasks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).

Comment: Create a console program and schedule it using Scheduled Tasks.

Comment: or if you are using SQL Server schedule a job to run, and send email via dbmail

Comment: @Vladimir, Any leads to how to create the console program and the scheduled task?

Comment: @Jeremy, I am using SQL Server. The email that get generated from the portion of that code comes from a submitted order which sends a reminder to the submitter to verify he/her order. This email does not get stored in the sql db. Any thought on how to proceed?

Comment: If you have freedom to change schema, add some fields to track whether/when you've sent a reminder email. Every X minutes run a query to find all orders in which no reminder was sent, then send an email using dbmail. You can specify the content of the email directly in sql code or table rather than the config file.

Comment: @Loic Create a Windows Console Application. Scheduled tasks can be configured via Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task scheduler.

Comment: You really, REALLY don't want to do this with a web site. Use a service or a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with comments on the scheduler. If you don't like that you can create a windows service that does this. This will solve if you want to fire the routine every X minutes.

You don't have enough code here to send out emails, so you have to wrap this with some logic that fires the routine with the email information you want. More than likely, this is stored in a database (recipients, email) or some other persistent store.

I do caution the idea of sending reminders every 15 minutes to the same people, as you are more than likely to piss them off (unless that is your intent?).

Comment: The email that get generated from the portion of that code comes from a submitted order which sends a reminder to the submitter to verify he/her order. The intent is to send a reminder, in order for submitter of the order to verify it.

Comment: If you do decide to go with Windows Service, be extra careful to detect and remove any possible memory leaks or it may crash your service (best case scenario) or server (worst case scenario). And do not trust GC to do work for you.

Comment: In that case, you put the user's email in a reminder queue and email him off the queue (NOTE: Queue here can be a table). You can then use a scheduler to check the queue every X minutes, or set up a service, etc. Personally, I would question the business user asking for this, as I have left shopping carts full and come back and deleted them or sent them based on my choice. It would tick me off to get a bunch of emails reminding me to submit the cart and I would likely stop doing business with a site that did this. Just my two cents.

Comment: Thank you all for you contributions. I have decided to create a SSIS package with a SQL and Send Email tasks. The SQL task check for new orders placed and the Send Email task sends reminder to users in a scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for you contributions. I have decided to create a SSIS package with a SQL and Send Email tasks. The SQL task check for new orders placed and the Send Email task sends reminder to users in a scheduled time.